# when i write the command this error i see

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, discord.py

```
    cur.execute(command, tuple(values))

    if (fetch := cur.fatchone()) is not None:
        return fetch[0]
```

```
    @bot_has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
    @has_permissions(manage_roles=True, manage_guild=True)
    async def unmute_members(self, ctx, members: Greedy[Member], *, reason: Optional[str] = "لا يكثر هرجك"):
        if not len(members):
            await ctx.send("!unmute @member [reason]")

        else:
            await self.unmute(ctx, members, reason=reason)
```

AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object has no attribute 'fatchone'

Comment: It's not `fatchone`. It's `fetchone`. FET, not FAT. `fetchone` means `fetch one`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo.

```py
    if (fetch := cur.fatchone()) is not None:
```

should be

```py
    if (fetch := cur.fetchone()) is not None:
```